I can't fetch documents from firebase database using flutter
i have collection named "Categories" in firebase and under this collection i have documents that i want to fetch . i defined the methode "getAllCategories" that is supposed to get the Categories from the db :
final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Future<List<CategoryModel>> getAllCategories() async {
    try {
      final snapshot = await _db.collection('Categories').get();
      final list =
          snapshot.docs.map((e) => CategoryModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList();
      print("${list}");
      return list;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw TFirebaseException(e.code).message;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      throw TPlatformException(e.code).message;
    } catch (e) {
      throw 'Something went wrong.Please try again';
    }
  }

and then i called this function in the "fetchCategories" function :
Future<void> fetchCategories() async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;

      final Categories = await _categoryRepository.getAllCategories();
      allCategories.assignAll(Categories);
      featuredCategories.assignAll(allCategories
          .where((category) => category.isFeatured && category.parentId.isEmpty)
          .take(8)
          .toList());
    } catch (e) {
      TLoader.errorSnackBar(
          title: 'Oh Snap mochkla fl caregori', message: e.toString());
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

lass CategoryModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String parentId;
  bool isFeatured;
  CategoryModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.image,
      required this.isFeatured,
      this.parentId = ''});

here is the category model:
there are no errors but after i did some tests i figured out that the method not working is the getAllCategories function.if anyone can give the possible reason for this problem he will save me days

Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. I recommend you debug locally yourself, and (if the problem is still not clear after that) tell us the results. So: set a breakpoint on the line that calls get(), run in the debugger until it hits that line, check if each variable on the line has the value you expect, if so: step to the next line and do the same. Continue this process until you find the first line where a variable is not what you expect it to be.
